# Having trouble creating a message object in GWT shared package

Tags: gwt

I have created a class in the GWT shared package, which I would like to be read by both client and server and also use it to pass messages between the client and the server. Here's the error message I'm getting when I try to start my project in Chrome. How do I fix this?

[ERROR] [project] - com.project.shared.Post is not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' or 'java.io.Serializable' nor does it have a custom field serializer (reached via com.project.shared.Post[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that you need your class to implement com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable (or java.io.Serializable, but prefer IsSerializable).

Since the class is traveling between your client and your server, it needs to be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code, I'd guess that you need to have your class implement IsSerializable so GWT can serialize it. That's the most likely reason you'd see that error.